# PostgreSQL how to compare a column's numeric value against the SUM of another numeric value?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and restored this Database in order to practice my Queries. It contains the following Tables:

[image]

What is the best query to find how many orders have an order_total that is less than the sum of their line_total(s)?

This is the query I have but I doubt that my number is accurate. I feel like I am doing something wrong:

```
select COUNT(order_total) from orders
join order_lines
on orders.id = order_lines.order_id
having count(order_total) < sum(line_total)
```

Am I querying correctly or not?

Thanks

- Pill

Answer (score 1):

perhaps something like this

```
select o.order_total,sum( l.line_total) as sum_line_total
from orders o join order_lines l on o.orders.id=l.order_id
group by o.order_total
having o.order_total < sum(l.line_total)
```

Answer (score 1):

That answer gave more than one result. I experimented and came across the correct answer by using the following sub-query:

```
select count(*) from orders,
(Select order_id, sum(line_total) from order_lines group by order_id) a
where order_total < a.sum and order_id = orders.id;
```

Thanks though for the response

- Pill